# Finding the max value in an array, however being less than the first number in the array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I need to find out how to find the max value in an array, being less than the first index of the array. So far, I have only found out how to find the maximum value in my array (shown below), but I need help only returning the max value less than the first number in my array from my method.

```
public static int findMaxOfLessThanFirst(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex, int firstNumber) {

if (endIndex == startIndex) {

    return numbers[endIndex];

}

else {

    int max = findMaxOfLessThanFirst(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1, firstNumber);   //Calling method using recursion.

    if (max < numbers[endIndex]) {

        return numbers[endIndex];

    }

    else {

        return max;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hint: so in other words, all numbers larger or equal than the first do not count, it's as if they were not there.

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition:

```
if (max < numbers[endIndex]) {
```

To:

```
if (max < numbers[endIndex] && numbers[endIndex] < firstNumber) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a recursive method is way overkill.

```
int maxLessThanFirst( int[] arr ) {
   int max = Integ3er.MIN_VALUE;
   for ( int i=1; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
      if ( arr[i] < arr[0] ) {
         <Do normal max value check here>
      }
   }
   return max;
}
```

Note that after the loop, if max=MIN_VALUE you need to have a check that there was at least one value < arr[0] (for example, if all other values are MIN_VALUE, the maximum is MIN_VALUE. If all other values are >= arr[0], you need to throw an exception to show that there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need two variables, one to store the first index so will have something to compare with and the other to store any value that is less than the first index while you loop through your array. And you keep replacing the second value to any number that is lower than what it currently holds.